# how to make all variations of list elements with "rules" Python?

Tags: python, combinations, combinatorics

Let's say we have the following list ["a","b","c","d"]. I want all variations that are of length 3. However i want to specify that certain elements can be sorted(in this case the first 2).["a","b","c"] = ["b","a","c"] but
["a","b","c"] != ["a","c","b"]

```
Input:
["a","b","c","d"]

Desired Output:
["a","b","c"]
["a","b","d"]
["a","c","b"]
["a","c","d"]
["a","d","b"]
["a","d","c"]
["b","c","a"]
["b","c","d"]
["b","d","a"]
["b","d","c"]
["c","d","a"]
["c","d","b"]
```

For my applications the list gets pretty big (around 10 to 20 elements) and variations are of length 10. Also i would like to be able to specify that a group of for example 3 elements can be sorted or that thay aren't the first 2 elements but for example the 4th and 5th can be sorted. I hope my question is clear.

Comment: That's not really practical.  You can certainly use `itertools.combinations` to generate all sets of 10 from a set of 20, and that's only 180,000 items, and each will all be sorted.  But for each combination, there are 3.6 million permutations, and that makes it impractical.